# Highlight matches 'quotes' and "double quotes"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting, double-quotes, single-quotes

How can I highlight matches for single quotes *('quotes')* and double quotes *("double quotes")*?

I read the docs and I saw there is something for brackets and tags:

```
"brackets_options":"foreground",
"brackets_foreground":"var(orange)",
"bracket_contents_options":"foreground",
"bracket_contents_foreground":"var(orange)",
"tags_options":"foreground",
"tags_foreground":"var(orange)",
```

but didn't found any solution for quotes.

Is there any option like `"quote_options"` or something like that with the same behavior as for brackets and tags?

I know about *BracketHighlighter* but this plugin is so slow and I generally prefer native options

I am working with:

- PHP, HTML, JS
- Default Mariana color scheme
- Default theme
- Sublime Text ver.: 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to highlight quotes, but you can select all between the quote tags by using **Selection | Expand selection to Scope** or shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Space</kbd> if you are looking for some functionality to "see" everything between the quotes.

Example when you click somewhere in between the quotes and use above mentioned functionality:

[image: Example select]